Error: Could not load main class org.openjdk.jmh.runner.ForkedMain
I am trying to create a new profile in maven that can run all the my JMH benchmark tests in the project.
The profile look something like below, I want my mvn verify -Dbenchmark to run all the benchmark tests.
<profiles>
   <profile>
       <id>benchmark</id>
       <activation>
           <property>
               <name>benchmark</name>
           </property>
       </activation>
       <properties>
           <benchmark.report>false</benchmark.report>
       </properties>
       <build>
           <plugins>
               <plugin>
                   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                   <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                   <executions>
                       <execution>
                           <phase>verify</phase>
                           <goals>
                               <goal>java</goal>
                           </goals>
                       </execution>
                   </executions>
                   <configuration>
                       <mainClass>org.openjdk.jmh.Main</mainClass>
                       <arguments>.*</arguments>
                       <classpathScope>test</classpathScope>
                   </configuration>
               </plugin>
           </plugins>
       </build>
   </profile>
</profiles>

However, as I assume from the exception below, one of the reason for this could be that classpath is not loaded correctly and I tried a bunch of ways to provide it. None works.
Could someone help me on what could be a potential problem for the following exception
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openjdk.jmh.runner.ForkedMain
<forked VM failed with exit code 1>
<stdout last='20 lines'>
</stdout>
<stderr last='20 lines'>
Error: Could not find or load main class org.openjdk.jmh.runner.ForkedMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openjdk.jmh.runner.ForkedMain
</stderr>

I have also tested running individual benchmark tests and I see they run without exception
Also, the reason for test classpath scope is because, it need to fild META-INF/benchmarklist to run all the tests as they are not in one place.
